# Angular2 update binding

Tags: angular

i have small question. I'll show my problem on this example:

```
    export class UserComponent {
      users: User[] = new Array<User>();
      removeAll(){
       this.users = new Array<User>();
      }
    }

<button (click)="removeAll">Remove</button>
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let user of users>{{user.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

When I click on remove button they should be empty  but ul has all previous values. How to refresh binding?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(click)="removeAll"
```

should be

```
(click)="removeAll()"
```